# Data type for a Quantity field

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a quantity field which store positive numbers such as 1, 2, 3 , etc

I gave it a type of Int , but I can save negative values inside it ? so which data type better represents my Quantity field ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A datatype of INT is fine. Its a [CHECK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) constraint you are missing. Add a constraint to stop negative values.

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE tlb ADD CONSTRAINT myCheckConstraint CHECK (myColumn >= 0);
```

Comment: you mean a constraint on my appliation side or inside the database side ?

Comment: @johnG, the client should have validation to stop that data getting to the database, the constraint stops the data going in for the cases it does get that far.